# Database normalization, should I combine these two tables?

Tags: normalization

I am sort of new to database normalization and working with a database that I did not create. The database has a table for users, and a separate table for user addresses. Both tables use the user id as their primary key, and every user is required to have an address. Since every user is required to have an address, should the information be added to the user table for proper normalization?

Comment: Does the user always have only one address associated with it? Does it never change? If it changes, do you need to know the old address? Are the answers to the previous questions guaranteed to never change?

Comment: ... Do security/access restrictions apply? If for example, the DBMS has table level access feature but not column level, splitting into 2 tables makes it easier to allow some db users to access (address, etc) details while others the (basic) user details.

Answer (score 2):

At the theoretical level, it does sound like these two tables can be combined.

At the practical level, unless you're rewriting everything that interacts with the database, no explicit significant harm should arise if you leave it as is.

If the only duplication of data is the user id, then the space to be gained from the change is minor, and probably not worth the cost of modifying your existing code to find the data in its new location.

If we knew more of the specifics of your situation, we might be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is not always necessary because theoretical sets are relatively poorly emulated by RDBMSes. There are always some limitations, overheads, slowdowns and bottlenecks that can be avoided by some denormalizations. Sure for educational purposes it is preferrable to represent each data type by separate table. When your scheme have types `user` and `address` then they have to be declared as two different tables. But in the real production projects sometimes we have to denormalize for sake of performance for example. Unfortunately, each specific case need some specific approach that can't be advised without some analysis.

For example table can represent the type "timestamped sensors readouts" like that:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| timestamp | sensor_id | readout |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

filled with millions of rows. When you want to get the last stored readout for each sensor that can take a while. But if you have the identical table where `sensor_id` field have UNIQUE index and all `INSERT`s have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, filled simultaneously with the main table then you can simply `SELECT *` from that table.

Normalization suggests that no different tables allowed that store the entitites of the same type. But in the real world this isn't a dogma.